# FS readFile returns nothing in a get request

Tags: node.js, express, fs

I am trying to return the values from a .txt file whenever someone makes a get request to my server.
But there problem is that I get undefined back all the time even though I have it asyncronous waiting for the result before I send it.
Could someone please help me out here?

This is my helper function that I call inside the get request.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fileName = './utils/readme.txt'

const getMoviesData = async () => {

  fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', (err, data) => {

      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
      console.log(data) // The text does show up here but not inside of my get request
      return data
    })
}

module.exports = getMoviesData
```

And this is my backend code.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();

// Utility functions (helpers)
const getMoviesData = require('./utils/getMoviesData')

const PORT = process.env.port || 5000

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {

  const data = await getMoviesData()
  console.log("Returns: " + data) // here is where all my problems start, it returns undefined
  res.send(data)
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
 console.log(`Listening on port: ` +  PORT)
})
```

I don't understand why this happens? Is my async/await syntax wrong?

Comment: Just want to make sure you see that you don't have to manually promisify `fs.readFile()`.  You can use the built-in promise support (in nodejs since v10) in the `fs` module by using `fs.promises.readFile()`.  See my answer for details and a very simple way to do this.

Comment: Honestly, it pisses me off that I can't accept both of your answers.
You are both right and both solutions work.
I just chose the one who was first because that's only fair, stackoverflow should fix this.
I do appreaciate your help.

Comment: No problem.  Just wanted to make sure you knew about the more modern way of using promises with file system access in nodejs.  Over time, if you earn more reputation, you can then upvote all helpful answers (still only "accept" one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return a promise and since `fs.readFile` uses callbacks you will have to wrap it in one.

In your code you did return a promise but you didn't `await` anything nor could you have since there is nothing to be awaited. Your console log logged the data because it was called async and your function returned nothing as the `return` statement happened in the async thread.

The below code should work

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const fileName = "./utils/readme.txt";

const getMoviesData = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(fileName, "utf8", (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      console.log(data);
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
};

module.exports = getMoviesData;
```

As @jfriend00 pointed out, you can also use the promised based `readFile` function that comes in with [node >= 10](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V10.md#10.0.0).

```js
const { readFile } = require("fs/promises");
const fileName = "./utils/readme.txt";

const getMoviesData = () => {
  return readFile(fileName, "utf8");
};

module.exports = getMoviesData;
```

Comment: `fs.promises` has been in nodejs since v10.

Answer (score -1):

You `getMoviesData()` function needs to return a promise that is resolved when your file operation is done.  Right now, it returns a promise (because it's declared as `async`) that is just immediately resolved before your file operation is done.

Since nodejs has built-in promise support for file operations already, I would suggest this implementation:

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;
const fileName = './utils/readme.txt'

const getMoviesData = () => {
  return fsp.readFile(fileName, 'utf8');
}

module.exports = getMoviesData
```

This way the promise that `getMoviesData()` returns is directly tied to when the file read operation is done and any errors are linked directly to a rejection of that promise.